# Getting range from a list using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of numbers such as

```
var list = ["123","12345678","123","234,2345","2.34567","123.12345","-123","-0.1234","-324215.45"];
```

This list can have negative, positive numbers with optional decimal values, also negative or positive.

I need to use regular expressions to do 3 things:

1. getAllNumbersBeforeValue(value);
2. getAllNumbersAfterValue(value);
3. getRangeBetweenValues(valueFrom, valueTo);

Value passed in is not known, could be any number.

**Update 1:**

I've got this, which isn't perfect but works on some numbers:

```
var a = function(rand) {
    var val = "";

    var numArr = rand.split("");
    for(var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
        val = val + (Number(numArr[i])+1);
    }
    return "^[^" + val.split("").join("-9][^") + "-9]$"
}; // outputs "^[^2-9][^3-9][^4-9][^5-9][^6-9]$" with rand "12345"
```

Im trying to get a regular expression programmatically generated from a given value
For example "123456" is a random number (rand), I would like to be able to filter an array of numbers for values that are higher then rand (or lower then rand) using a regex value.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you use RegEx to do that?

Comment: It's a requirement :(

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your problem/requirements? I don't quite get it.

Comment: Why can't you just parse those strings to numbers and compare them using bigger than / smaller than?

Comment: I don't understand your need for using a RegExp, but if it is an absolute MUST then perhaps you could show us what you have tried? What problem you are having with the RegExps that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could use underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org) to filter your results. For example...

```
var list = ["123","12345678","123","234,2345","2.34567","123.12345","-123","-0.1234","-324215.45"];

function getAllNumbersBeforeValue(list, value) {
    return _.filter(list, function(num) { 
        return num < value; 
    });
}
```

Here's an example without using a framework...

```
function getAllNumbersBeforeValue(list, value) {
    var output = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(list[i] < value) {
            output.push(list[i]);
        }
    }
    return output;
}



getAllNumbersBeforeValue(list, 123);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I cant use any frameworks but dojotoolkit.